# Android Endless Adapter

Tags: android, endlessadapter

Im using the endless adapter http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless  however whenever i return false (because i dont have anymore data to append) , as stated here http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/blob/master/README.markdown  in appendinbackground, my activity crashes and in Logcat i get a message saying indexoutofbounds etc.

How do I make it so that I can stop loading extra data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on [the page you linked to](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless):

> If you have questions regarding the
>   use of this code, please join and ask
>   them on the [cw-android Google
>   Group](http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android). Be sure to indicate which
>   CWAC module you have questions about.

We will need your stack trace as well, showing the exception.

Comment: @VeryVito: You will notice this answer is nearly three years old. If you read [the component's README](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless), you will see that support is now through StackOverflow. Please follow the instructions in that README.

Comment: I'm using endless adapter with gridview. Example shows progress image at bottom left, but I want to show it at bottom center. But even after I write android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" (of course my grid view and image are inside relativeLayout) after I run project it shows at bottom left.
where shall I make changes?

Comment: @NayAneshGupte: The only way to get what you want would be for you to have an odd number of columns, then always load in a number of elements that would cause the pending `View` to wind up in the center column. `EndlessAdapter` itself does not control positioning of elements within the `AdapterView` -- that is up to the `AdapterView` itself.